# using switch statement to provide action to jbuttons java

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, jbutton

I'm trying to use switch for triggering a button's statement. I've programmed frame1 to open `JFrame` of 2nd class. In 2nd class there are four buttons which will work on `Switch` statement and I'm using a variable from 1st class to work as choice for `Switch`, but I'm getting a null pointer exception. Why so?

Class1( BasicInfo.java)

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    name= n.getText();
    email=e.getText();
    street=s.getText();
    state=st.getText();
    city=c.getText();
    gender=(String)g.getSelectedItem();
    qualification=(String)q.getSelectedItem();
    date=Integer.parseInt((String)d.getSelectedItem());
    month=Integer.parseInt((String)m.getSelectedItem());
    year=Integer.parseInt(y.getText());
    phone_num=Integer.parseInt(nm.getText());
    //this.dispose();
                    new ViewSample().setVisible(true);
    }
```

Class 2(ViewSample.java)

```
void open()
{
    BasicInfo x= new BasicInfo();
    System.out.print(x.qualification);
    switch(x.qualification)
    {
        case "BE":
            System.out.print("a");
            break;
            case "MBA":
            System.out.print("b");
                break;
            default:
    }
}

private void s1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    open();
}

private void s4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    open();
}

private void s2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    open();
}

private void s3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    open();
}

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    this.dispose();
}
```

Comment: In the description you are saying, you passing the reference of the first class to the second class. Though inside the `open()` method, it seems you recreating the object of the first class, and it's value for `qualification` is not yet set. Are you sure it is printing something genuine? You need to do something like `new ViewSample(this).setVisible(true)` and then in the constructor of `ViewSample` do `this.x = x`, where the latter is the reference of `BasicInfo` that it received from the `actionPerformed` of the `JButton` and the former is an instance variable `BasicInfo x` of `ViewSample`

Comment: @nIcEcOw I know I'm making a new reference but I don't know how to make an object public?

Comment: IMHO, simply start from the scratch, create just the code with debug material, just check if you getting all print statements in the right way. Then slowly add thingies to it, and see they are received on the other side as intended. You are trying to make the software in one go, which is not the good way. Go step by step, check it at each step, regarding the authenticity of it's functionality and then move on. Wait let me, give a small example.

Comment: @nIcEcOw can u please edit the code in answer. I'm not getting it.

Comment: @nIcEcOw the problm is solved now.. I've made that field static :)
btw Thanx :)

Comment: No this is the biggest mistake that you did, by making the field static. Use of unnecessary static thingies is again a design flaw in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comments, I was of the opinion of doing something like, as shown in this code example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PassingValuesExample {

    private String qualification;
    private JTextField qualificationField;
    private JButton submitButton;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Worker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        qualificationField = new JTextField(10);
        submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                submitButtonActionPerformed(ae);
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(qualificationField);
        contentPane.add(submitButton);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void submitButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        qualification = qualificationField.getText();
        new Foo(this).open();
    }

    public String getQualification() {
        return qualification;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PassingValuesExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class Foo {

    private PassingValuesExample pve;

    public Foo(PassingValuesExample pve) {
        this.pve = pve;
    }

    public void open() {
        String qual = pve.getQualification();
        switch(qual) {
            case "CA":
            case "MBA":
                System.out.println("Qualification: " + qual);
        }
    }
}
```